# Should I keep duplicate sites listed in Google Search Console as both HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: google-search-console

[image]

I want to clear some confusion here. I have same  website listed with HTTP and HTTPS in Google Search Console. Initially I added `http://www.example.com` and then later I switched to `https://www.example.com`.

Should I keep these two URLs added as it is? or I should remove the first one with HTTP? The important thing I noticed that after submitting 45 URLs, I am getting 0 indexed URLs.

Comment: There is no harm in keeping multiple versions of your site verified in Google Search Console.

Comment: When you say that you submitted 45 URLs, which property did you submit them to, the HTTP or HTTPS?   Which protocol do the URLs in the sitemap use?   How did you handle the HTTP site now that HTTPS is enabled?   Do they both have the same content?   Do you use canonical tags?   Do you redirect the HTTP version?